# How to set layout_width of an image pragmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am trying to set layout_width to FILL_PARENT to an image view. I am using following code::

```
    ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);
                   image.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_ac_line);
                   LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                   image.setLayoutParams(lp);
                   layout.addView(image);
```

But its not working.

Can any please suggest me the answer for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what layout do you use, and is your layoutParam imported from the same layout class? also, is your layout fill_parent?

Comment: why don't you accept any answer?

Comment: Thanks for response. I am using Linear layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be importing LayoutParams

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
```

instead it try

```
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it won't help to set plain LayoutParams, you need to create/set specialized LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams / LinearLayout.LayoutParams / etc) depending on what kind of LayoutParams is used by layout where your view is added.

Each Layout class has own specialized LayoutParams class and work only with this.
So the answer depends on class of your "layout" object. Fix by above advice.

Comment: Hi mice. Thanks for yuor response. even I used following code:  android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   image.setLayoutParams(lp); But this code also did not work